# Wavy line in a WPF Window

Tags: wpf

There's already solutions to draw wavy lines in a [FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632450/wavy-underlines-in-a-flowdocument) and [somewhere else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/633678/wavy-underlines-as-a-textdecoration-what-i-am-doing-wrong), but they don't quite work to draw a wavy line as a plain visual control in a window. When I try the first linked solution, I get a double line instead of a single line, and it's a bit pale as well. Playing with the Thickness value or the Line control only makes it worse.

The combination of a Line using a VisualBrush using a Path seems complicated enough, but when I think I could need a Rectangle using a DrawingBrush using a Pen using a VisualBrush using a Path is entirely too much.

I'd also prefer a solution in plain C# because this is generated and used dynamically. But I could also use a resource defined in XAML to use in the generated object.