# Does WPF RichTextBox support squiggly underline and inline images?

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

I need and editable component that supports these 2 features:

- inline images
- squiggly underlines that can have custom collor (different to text above them).

Does WPF RichTextBox support that? If not, what does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RichTextBox displays FlowDocuments which do support inline images through the use of a [BlockUIContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.blockuicontainer.aspx). They don't support squiggly underlines by default, but you can create a custom style as [shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632450/wavy-underlines-in-a-flowdocument).