# Adding a "Red Squiggle" underline programmatically in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Wavy underlines in a FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632450/wavy-underlines-in-a-flowdocument)

I have a form in which I need to be able to programmatically add red squiggle error underlines to runs within a flow document, but really have no idea where to start.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: still +1 for "Red Squiggle" as a keyword for search engines ;-)

Comment: I don't think that this is a duplicate personally, since I need to change it in the code behind; however, the solution appears to be to put the code from the "duplicate" into a resource dictionary.  Then you can access it with (VirtualBrush)Resources["WavyBrush"] in the code behind.