# Wavy underlines in WinRT

Tags: user-interface, winrt-xaml, windows, c++-cx

In other Xaml frameworks, you can add wavy underlines like in the following link:

[Wavy underlines in a FlowDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632450/wavy-underlines-in-a-flowdocument)

However these no longer work in the Windows Apps Xaml. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Using Direct2D with DirectWrite is one option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XAML's existing class PathGeometry to draw wavy lines. 
Or, if you choose to use D2D, you can use ID2D1GeometrySink::AddBezier().